# Allign text in multirow and rotatebox used in a table to other columns

Tags: multirow

I would like to centering a vertical text in a column to the other cells. My example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}



\begin{tabular}{lcc}
    \toprule
     &Description  & Description  \\ \midrule
    \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Test sideways}} & test & 1.0 \\[1.5ex]
     & test & 1.0  \\[1.5ex]
    & test & 1.0  \\[1.5ex]
    & test & 1.0  \\[1.5ex]
    & test & 1.0\\[1.5ex]
    & test & 1.0  \\[1.5ex]
     & test & 1.0  \\ \bottomrule

\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Running this gives the following table:

[image]

'Test sideways' is not aligned to the other cells reading test and 1.0. Is there a way to make the vertical text centred to the other cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

With use of the `tabularray`, `rotating` and `makecell` packages is no that hard:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}   % needed
\usepackage{makecell}   % needed
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{ Test sideways }
\begin{tblr}{colspec={ccc},
             cell{2-Z}{1} = {cmd=\rotcell[cc]},}
    \toprule
    &   Description &   Description     \\ 
    \midrule
\SetCell[r=7]{c} Test sideways
    & test & 1.0    \\
    & test & 1.0    \\
    & test & 1.0    \\
    & test & 1.0    \\
    & test & 1.0    \\
    & test & 1.0    \\
    & test & 1.0    \\  
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Zarko! Is there a way to break the words, e.g. something like: Test \\ sideways?

Comment: Found a way myself: \makecell{Test \\ sideways}

Comment: @MCK1886, in spirit of `tabularray` package two line text can be achieved by `\SetCell[r=7]{c} {Test\\ sideways}`. I wonder, why you split text when there is enough space  for one line? Well, this is up to you :-)